# Question regarding errand on UITableView creation from iPhone Addressbook

Tags: uitableview, memory-management, ios4, addressbook

I have a question regarding the AddressBook Framework for iOS. The situation is as follows:

I'm trying recreate the contacts view from the phone application, but I want to show the contact's phone numbers in the same view. So if a contact has more than one number, his name will be in the TableView multiple times, each time with a different number.

I am trying to accomplish that by extracting all the information I need when the view loads and after that, populate the TableView with the appropriate values from an NSArray consisting of NSDictionaries containing the contact's information.

This works great except for one thing... The contact's phonenumbers and labels are read correctly and stored in the dictionary, but when I read them out later, they seem to have vanished.

Here's my code for generating the NSDictionaries, I bet it's some kind of memory management error or something completly stupid. I hope anyone can help me, thanks a lot in advance!

```
persons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
NSArray *people = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByLastName);

for (id record in people)
{
    ABMultiValueRef numbers = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonPhoneProperty); 

    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(numbers); ++i) {
        CFStringRef label = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(numbers, i));
        CFStringRef number = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers, i);
        CFStringRef firstNameRef = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        CFStringRef lastNameRef = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        CFDataRef imageDataRef = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat((ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);

        NSString *firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", firstNameRef];
        NSString *lastName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", lastNameRef];
        NSString *pLabel = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", label];
        NSString *pNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", number];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData*)imageDataRef];

        NSDictionary *personDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:firstName, @"firstName", lastName, @"lastName", image, @"image", pNumber, @"phoneNumber", pLabel, @"label", nil];
        NSLog(@"In %@ - %@", pLabel, pNumber);

        [persons addObject:personDict];

        CFRelease(firstNameRef);
        CFRelease(lastNameRef);
        //CFRelease(imageDataRef);
        CFRelease(label);
        CFRelease(number);
    }
}

CFRelease(addressBook);
CFRelease(source);
[people release];
```

Comment: I kind of got a solution to this myself when I tried debugging on a device. It seems that this behaviour is only apparent in the simulator. On my iPhone it works mostly, but not for all contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Finally could resolve this myself. Apparently I was adding some nil-images to the dictionaries which they couldn't handle.

Comment: When I take out the lines where I get the image information from the address book it works perfectly as it should... I'm looking further into it.